# Why does IntelliJ keep removing backticks from this JavaScript template string?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, ecmascript-6, backticks, template-strings

I want to put "backticks" around my [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

**IntelliJ** keeps **removing** them every time I try the wrap them around the string.

Anyone's got a clue why its happening and how to solve this?

I added a little code snippet of my *.vue file where the problem occurred. Imagine html, js and css written down in one component (*.vue) file, separated by unique tags (template, script and style tag).
I am using a german keyboard layout with the Mac OS X 10.5+ keymap.

[image: intelliJ removing backticks]

```js
import axios from "axios";
import 'vue-animate/dist/vue-animate.min.css';

export default {
  name: 'hello',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: `Service is <strong>ONLINE</strong> and <strong>READY</strong> to operate`,
      clicked: false,
      iconURL:"./../../static/img/meditate.svg",
      meditationAction: this.activateMeditation,
      backgroundImage: "",
      room:"Bad"

    }
  },
  methods:{
      activateMeditation () {
          this.clicked = !this.clicked;

          axios.get(`http://localhost:5005/${this.room}/shuffle/on`).then(response => {
              console.info("SUCCESSFULLY ACTIVATED SHUFFLE");

            axios.get(`http://localhost:5005/${this.room}/volume/20`).then(response => {
              console.info("SUCCESSFULLY SET VOLUME TO 20");

              axios.get("http://localhost:5005/bad/sleep/900").then(response => {
                console.info("SUCCESSFULLY SET SLEEP TIME TO 15 MINUTES");

                axios.get("http://localhost:5005/bad/playlist/med").then(response => {
                  console.info("SUCCESSFULLY SET PLAYLIST TO MED");
                  this.iconURL = "./../../static/img/stop.svg";
                  this.meditationAction = this.pausePlayback;

                  axios.get("http://localhost:5005/bad/state").then(response => {
                    console.info("SUCCESSFULLY RETRIEVED STATE");
                    console.log(response);
                    //FIXME: USE IMAGE OF CURRENT TRACK INSTEAD OF NEXT TRACK
                    this.backgroundImage = response.data.nextTrack.absoluteAlbumArtUri;
                  })
                  .catch((error)=>{
                    console.log(error);
                  });

                })
                .catch((error)=>{
                  console.log(error);
                });

              })
              .catch((error)=>{
                console.log(error);
              });

            })
            .catch((error)=>{
              console.log(error);
            });

          })
          .catch((error)=>{
            console.log(error);
            this.iconURL = "./../../static/img/attention.svg";
            this.meditationAction = this.resetButton;
          });


      },

    pausePlayback() {

      axios.get("http://localhost:5005/bad/pause").then(response => {
        console.info("SUCCESSFULLY PAUSED PLAYBACK");
        this.iconURL = "./../../static/img/meditate.svg";
        this.meditationAction = this.activateMeditation;
        this.backgroundImage = "";
      })
      .catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error);
      });

    },

    resetButton() {

      this.iconURL = "./../../static/img/meditate.svg";
      this.meditationAction = this.activateMeditation;

    }



  }
}
```

```css
 * {

    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .logo {
    max-width:50%;
  }

  .svg {
    height:5em;
    z-index:100;
  }

  .option .svg .st0 {
    fill: white;
    stroke: white;
  }

  .options__container {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width:100%;


  }

  .option {

    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height:3em;
    width:3em;

    position:relative;

    background-size:cover;

    padding:3em;
    border-radius:100%;
    background-color:white;
    border-top:3px solid black;
    border-bottom:5px solid #303030;
    border-left:3px solid black;
    border-right:7px solid #303030;



    transition: all 300ms ease-in;

  }

  .option__background-image {


    position:absolute;
    background-color:white;
    opacity:0.8;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
  }

  .option:hover {

    border:3px solid black;

  }
```

```html
  <div class="hello">
    <img class="logo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/10/Sonos_2015-Logo.png"/>
    <h2 v-html="msg"></h2>
    <div class="options__container">
      <a class="option" v-on:click="meditationAction" v-bind:class="{'animated flash' : clicked}" :style="{backgroundImage: 'url(' + backgroundImage +')'}" >
        <div class="option__background-image" ></div>
        <img class="svg" :src=iconURL>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: the more I look at this gif the less I understand what's going on. Please can you provide original code snippet (as text) and describe steps to repeat? what is your system keyboard layout?

Comment: i've added the code snippet for the component i was working on and added a little description to further explain the content structure. I hope this helps.

Comment: So, you had `axios.get(http://localhost:5005/${this.room}/shuffle/on).then(response => {` in your code, and tried to surround "http://localhost:5005/${this.room}/shuffle/on" with backticks? Or, tried to replace quotes with backticks? Or? What is your keyboard layout?

Comment: Yes i tried to **surround** "localhost:5005/${this.room}/shuffle/on" with backticks. But  **replacing** double quotes with backticks didn't work either. I am using QWERTZ keyboard layout.

Comment: may be the https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21750 issue; please follow it for updates

Comment: @lena Update? You got to be joking. The last update was 2016. JetBrains will do **nothing** about it. I'd suggest you switch to VS Code. A much smoother experience, open source and **free**.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have the same problem. I solved it by disabling the "Insert pair quote" option in Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Smart Keys.

Of course, it disables the inserting of pair quotes for all types of quotes, including single and double. It's a temporary workaround, but personally I'd rather actually be able to use JS's template strings despite having to type in the pair of quotes every time.

Comment: Seems to be the best fix at the current time. Thanks :)

Comment: an even batter fix would it to implement proper string format function in ES6 or 7. How about pythons approach with a call to a build in format function on each string. This is the fastest way to format a string, since you don't have to change anything if you want to use formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is to write a backtick in another location and copy/paste it around the template.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the insert pair quote option is a bad workaround, a better approach to deal with this is creating a live template with backticks.

Just go to Preferences -> Editor -> Live templates, create a custom template with a shortcut word (form me is tpl) containing **``**, and to use this in code just type tpl+Tab key and done

Answer (score 0):

Just had this "feature" (five years later) and figured out a simple solution, just hit back-tick one more time that will get the closing back-tick to stick with no preference changed in v.2022.2.3

back-tick text text back-tick back-tick